# Go to App Store Reviews in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, xamarin.ios, xamarin

It appears that using the itms-apps//.... URL scheme doesn't work in iOS 6 with the new App Store to show the product reviews area.  Now I'm using the code below, but it just shows you the product.  How do you get to the review area to ask for a review and take the user to the right tab of the product displayed?

```
    void DoReview()
    {
        var spp = new StoreProductParameters(appId);
        var productViewController = new SKStoreProductViewController();
        // must set the Finished handler before displaying the view controller
        productViewController.Finished += (sender2, err) => {
            // Apple's docs says to use this method to close the view controller
            this.navigationController.DismissViewController(true, null);
            MySettings.AskedForReview = true;
        };
        productViewController.LoadProduct(spp, (ok, err) => { // ASYNC !!!
            if (ok)
            {
                this.navigationController.PresentViewController(productViewController, true, null);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" failed ");
                if (err != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(" with error " + err);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can, but you should not. If an App is nagging me "vote me", I'm going to delete it. In a WWDC talk from 2012, I remember that this "vote me" was one of the things to NOT to have a good app. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you could try [iRate from Nick Lockwood](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) and see if that fits your needs, you can find the [MonoTouch bindings of iRate here](https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.iRate).

btw it uses the following URL to open AppStore in review mode:

> itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id= your-AppID-here

Alex

Comment: Thanks, the itms-apps link doesn't seem to work in iOS 6, that is exactly what I used in the past.

Comment: mmm, weird, I tested it myself using iRate and it works as expected, it takes me to review area of my own app under iOS 6

Comment: iRate has a property called displayAppUsingStorekitIfAvailable, which determines whether or not it uses StoreKit. If you choose to use StoreKit it appears that there is no way to default to the reviews tab.